# Partition or Index large table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016, partitioning

I have a large table consisting of 4 Billion+ rows and 50 columns, most of which are either `datetime` or `numeric` except a few which are `varchar`.

Data will be inserted into the table on a weekly basis (about 20 million rows).

I expect queries with where clauses on some of the `datetime` columns, and a couple of the the `varchar` columns. There is no primary key in the table.

There are no indexes, nor the table is partitioned. I am using SQL Server 2016.

I understand that I need to partition or index the table, but I am not sure which approach to take or both in-fact.

Since the table is large, should I create the indexes first or should I create the partitions first? If I do create the indexes and then create the partitions, what should I do to maintain these with new data coming in weekly.

**EDIT**: Also, minimal updates and deletes are expected on the table

Comment: Partitioning and indexing is done for very different purposes.Indexing is way more common and I'd start with looking at the queries that need to be fast and creating indexes to support them.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBaranov. Most of the queries will be filtering on the datetime columns and on some of the varchar columns. Like, get data for a certain daterange for a certain entity. With the indexes, it will be fragmented a lot because of new inserts and rebuilding/reorganising the indexes will also consume a lot of time. I can do it but again not sure which approach.

Comment: `There are no indexes,` that's a huge problem. Query performance *depends* on indexes. Without them the server has to scan the entire 4B rows. Partitioning is a data management feature, *not* a performance feature. If you want to search by date, index the date columns.

Comment: Another option is to create a [clustered columnstore index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-2016), effectively indexing all columns while *compressing* the data at the same time. A columnstore can offer 100x acceleration for data warehouse/star schema scenarios due to compression, in-memory processing and columnar storage.

Comment: @siddharth what is this table used for? Is it a fact table? How did it grow to 4B rows without indexes? You'll probably get a better answer if you describe the actual use case/problem.

Comment: Depending on the usage of the table, you might try with the [ColumnStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017) index?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Its not a Fact table. Its just a backfill of historic data that we have recieved. Hence, no indexes on it yet. Going forward, we will add rows to it on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that I need to partition or index the table

You need to understand what you gain from partitioning. It is not at all the case that SQL Server requires partitioning on big tables to function adequately. SQL Server scales to arbitrary tables sizes without any inherent issues.

Common benefits of partitioning are:

1. Mass deletion in constant time
2. Different storage for older partitions
3. Not backing up old partitions

Sometimes in special situations (e.g. columnstore), partitioning can help as a strategy to speed up queries. Normally, indexing is better for that.

Essentially, partitioning splits the table physically into multiple sub tables. Most often this has a *negative* effect on query plans. Indexes are perfectly capable of restricting the set of data that needs to be touched. Partitions are worse for that.

> Most of the queries will be filtering on the datetime columns and on some of the varchar columns. Like, get data for a certain daterange for a certain entity. With the indexes, it will be fragmented a lot because of new inserts and rebuilding/reorganising the indexes will also consume a lot of time. I can do it but again not sure which approach.

It seems you can best solve this by indexing:

1. Index according to the queries you expect.
2. Maintain the indexes properly. This is not too hard. For example, rebuild them after the weekly load.

> Since the table is large, should I create the indexes first or should I create the partitions first?

Set up that partitioning objects first. Then, create or rebuild the clustered index on the new partitioning scheme. If possible drop other indexes first and recreate them afterwards (might not work due to availability restrictions).

> what should I do to maintain these with new data coming in weekly.

What concerns do you have? New data will be stored in the appropriate partitions automatically. Make sure to create new partitions before loading the data. Keep partitions ready for 2 weeks in advance. The latest partitions must always be empty to avoid costly splits.

> There is no primary key in the table.

Most often this is a not a good design. Most tables should have a primary key and a clustered index. If there is no natural key use an artifical one such as a `bigint identity`.

---

You definitely can apply partitioning but my feeling is that it will not gain you what you maybe expect. But it will force you to take on additional maintenance burdens, possibly reduce performance and there is risk of making mistakes that threaten availability. Simplicity is important.

Comment: If you have follow up questions please post a comment.

Comment: The OP seems to describe a fact table, in which case a columnstore index would be appropriate. I have to wonder though, how did they get to 4B rows without indexes?

Comment: @usr - Thanks a lot for the answer. I now think I will try creating the indexes first. The thing I was worried about was rebuilding the indexes could take somewhere in the order of 14-15 hours and with the table expected to grow by a billion rows every year, this may be a problem later on.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The reason there are no indexes on it at the moment is because this is a dump of data that has been provided as a backfill. I need to set up new jobs to fetch the data in weekly basis going forward and insert it into the table.

Comment: @siddharth you *really* need to explain your use case because index rebuilds can be done online in the Enterprise edition and simply *isn't* needed in most cases. Indexes are updated automatically after all. 20M rows for a columnstore index isn't a lot of data - its built to update data in 1M row deltas.

Comment: @siddharth did you think of dropping indexes during bulk inserts perhaps? You probably don't need to. First of all, 4B isn't a lot of data nowadays. Second columnstores can easily handle batch inserts. Finally, partitioning can be used to move data between staging and target/fact tables quickly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for the columnstore idea. I have no experience on the columnstore data and I am reading it now, but from what I gather is that data needs to be stored in a different way first. An online index rebuild is probably not needed as we can do it on the weekend which should be ok. The use case is this data will be analysed to get aggregates on some columns (mostly numeric) to calculate year on year or quarterly metrics for the named entities. The data is mostly financial with columns like price, net, gross etc which will be aggregated based on year/month for the entities.

Comment: @siddharth that's the golden scenario for columnstores! Clustered columnstore indexes *don't* need to store the original data in a different location anyway. The table itself becomes a columnstore. It's only *non*-clustered columnstores that are stored separately. Check [Use a clustered columnstore index for large data warehouse tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-2016#use-a-clustered-columnstore-index-for-large-data-warehouse-tables)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Sounds great. But I have no clue to how to do it :) Can you give me some pointers. (I will check out the msdn post) Thanks. Or probably post it as an answer. I will try both the indexing and the columnstore idea then and hopefully be able to post  back an answer in a few days.